# Validar formulario de contacto con js

Tags: javascript, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

soy nuevo en MVC y JS, lo que quiero es validar un formulario de contacto antes de que pase a la acción del controlador. Intente hacer un script pero no me funciona y no se porque. Este es mi form y mi script.

```js
function submit() {
        var form = document.getElementsByName('formCont')[0],
            elementos = form.elements,
            boton = document.getElementById('btnSubmit');

        var validarNombre = function () {
            if (form.nombre.value == 0) {
                alert('completar campo nombre')
            }
        }

        var validar = function () {
            validarNombre();
        }

        form.addEventListener("submit", validar);
    }
```

```html
<form style="color:black" method="post" action="" id="formContacto" name="formCont">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 offset-md-3">
            <label for="nombre"><strong>Nombre</strong></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-12" name="nombre" placeholder="Ingresa tu nombre">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @*<button id="btnSubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">ENVIAR</button>*@
                <button id="btnSubmit" onclick="submit" class="btn btn-primary">ENVIAR</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Probablemente el script este mal, ya que lo fui haciendo con lo que vi en Internet. Alguna sugerencia? Gracias.

Comment: Si estas utilizando MVC para el proyecto podrias hacer esas validaciones en el mismo codigo de C#, te dejo [este](https://anexsoft.com/asp-net-mvc-validando-un-formulario-y-eliminando-registros) link para que lo revises =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar `jQuery Validation`:

Añadir los siguientes scripts al `Layout` page:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-x.x.x.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

Añadir esta function a la pagína de View:

```
$(function () {
    $("#SubmitButton").click(function () {
        if (!$("#frmCreate").valid()) {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Añadir necesario `Data Annotations` al `Entity Model` properties:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = " Required field!")]
[StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long", MinimumLength = 2)]
[MaxLength(50)]
public string Name { get; set; }


[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required field!")]
[EmailAddress]
[RegularExpression("^[a-z0-9_\\+-]+(\\.[a-z0-9_\\+-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9]+)*\\.([a-z]{2,4})$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid e-mail")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Añadir `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` to the related inputs.

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "input" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name, null, new { @class = "field-validation-error" })
```

Espero que esto ayude...